# how to Add an Expires or a Cache-Control Header for php platform

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, http, apache2

I'm bilding a web site in PHP Platform. I got some info like an Expires or a Cache-Control Header will help to load web site faster. I do't know how to enable it.

pls tell me the procedure in step by step.

where to change the settings. how to do it and all

if you explain with an example that helps me better. Thank You.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
 Header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");

 $offset = 60 * 60 * 24 * 3;
 $ExpStr = "Expires: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $offset) . " GMT";
 Header($ExpStr);
?>
```

Comment: Uh.. why is the date in the past? This guy wants to enable caching, not to disable it.